# Функция с методами, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: javascript, методы

Задача такова :
Функция должна вернуть объект, у которого должно быть несколько методов:
sum - складывает number с переданными аргументами
dif - вычитает из number переданные аргументы
div - делит number на первый аргумент. Результат делится на следующий аргумент (если
передан) и так далее
mul - умножает number на первый аргумент. Результат умножается на следующий
аргумент (если передан) и так далее

Решил я это вот так

```
let calc = function calculator(number) {
    let result = number;
    let obj = {
        sum : function () {
            for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
                result+=arguments[i];
            }
            return result;
        },
        dif : function () {
            for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
                result -= arguments[i];
            }
            return result;
        },
        div : function () {
            for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
                if (arguments[i] == 0) {
                    throw new Error('Na nol delit nelzya!');
                } else {
                    result /= arguments[i];
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
        mul : function () {
            for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
                result *= arguments[i];
            }
            return result;
        },

    }
    return obj;

}

let calcfn = calc;

let mycalc = calcfn(10);


console.log(mycalc.sum(3,2)); // 15
try {
    console.log(mycalc.div(2));  // 7.5
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}
```

Но проблема заключается в том, что второй метод, у меня например это деление, выполняется не от 10, которая передана в number, а от результата суммы. Что можно сделать, чтобы все методы выполнялись от переданного в качестве аргумента числа, а не от предыдущего результата выполнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прочитайте про [области видимости](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) переменных, как вариант внести `let result = number` в сами функции `sum`, `dif`, `div`, `mul`.

Есть и другие варианты решения, но судя по вашему коду **ожидаемый** результат отличается от **действительного** и поэтому лучше в рамках заданного вопроса почитать про области видимостей, затем можно изменить текущий код на более компактную и чистую реализацию

Для понимания областей видимости можете рассмотреть этот код:

```
let calc = function calculator(number) {
  //let result = number;
  let obj = {
    sum : function () {
      let result = number;
      for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
          result+=arguments[i];
      }
      return result;
    },
    div : function () {
      let result = number;
      for (let i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
          if (arguments[i] == 0) {
              throw new Error('Na nol delit nelzya!');
          } else {
              result /= arguments[i];
          }
      }
      return result;
    },
  }
  // ... остальные функции

  return obj
}

let calcfn = calc;

let mycalc = calcfn(10);

console.log(mycalc.sum(3,2)); // вернет 15
try {
    console.log(mycalc.div(2));  // вернет 5
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял